# How would I isolate the scale on my ball so it does not affect the tail?

Tags: animation, mesh

I am animating a ball with tail and when I scale the ball down for squash and stretch it affects the tail mesh with it. How would I put it so when I squash the ball with the bone, the tail will still follow the ball without the tail also squashing with it?

Comment: Hello Gavin, do you know about proportional editing?  if you are using a mouse with a middle wheel, you select your vertex, turn it on (its in  tiny button in the top bar, no way you would know about it unless you look up where it is in the UI) and then use the middle wheel to scroll in or out for the radius that the grab effect is going to use to squash the ball.

Comment: Hello maybe share your file so that we understand how you've organized the object?

Comment: @WhisperingShiba He is squashing the ball with an armature bone - _Proportional Editing_ cannot be used here.

Comment: Yes so he should create another bone for the tail

Comment: I have created an armature for the ball and tail but when i squash the ball it still scales the tail along with it when I parent the tail to the ball or join the meshes. Is the only option to animate the ball and tail separately or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

For the tail bone, in the *Bone panel > Relations > Inherit Scale*, choose *None*, when you'll scale the parent, the child won't be deformed:

[image]

Comment: That works if i need to scale the tail, but I need to squash and stretch the ball bone while the tail mesh stays attached to the ball and stays the same scale

Comment: It would help if you showed some pictures or even shared your file